# Qt creator: Widget is not added to layout

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qwidget, qtgui

So I have a GUI I designed in QT creator.

Because I have to add a createWindowContainer widget, I have to add a widget to my code via c++. I am adding a simple label to test the best way to this. Unfortunately, though the program compiles, the widget is not shown.

My main window is in fact shown, sans the desired widget.

So I have these lines:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{


     ui->setupUi(this);

     ui->gridLayout->addWidget(new QLabel("test"),0,0);

     // MainWindow does other stuff 

     ui->setupUi(this);
```

From what I've read, this should be correct. What am I doing wrong? Is there a good way to debug this?

Edit: Found the problem. Added a second ui->setupUi to reflect the error that caused the problem. If you call this twice, it appears to erase any widgets you added after you call it the first time.

Comment: Which one is not shown, the label or your widget?

Comment: I am adding a label widget. It is not being shown. It should show a label that says "test." Hypothetically I could put any widget where it says new Qlabel("test") - right?

Comment: Your code (so far) is ok. Show some more code. There must be some other error. By the way: It's Qt, not QT.

Comment: Yes, your code of this part is definitely right. Theoretically it should be shown.

Comment: Maybe you could provide more information on how you come to this step.

Comment: Are your main window shown? Is the layout set to be the layout of the main window? I'm not using qt creator, so I don't know if how the layout is added to the main window.

Comment: Found the problem. I had called ui->setupUi(this) twice.

Comment: @DominikSelzer the code is fine???

Comment: @Tay2510 he code is fine???

Comment: @andrea.marangoni The code has been edited after original post found the problem. As we left the comment, there is only one line of `ui->setupUi(this);` (you can check what he has edited).

Comment: Yes ... in the original post there was no second setupUi ... :-).

Comment: oh..in this case.. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the UI setup method twice, but more importantly: the second call is made after the explicit widget addition to the "default" UI.

That is not good because then the widget is "cleared" by the second since it will set up the UI based on your UI file again which does not contain the widget as that is added explicitly, so just remove that line.

Therefore, you should be writing this instead:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{


     ui->setupUi(this);

     ui->gridLayout->addWidget(new QLabel("test"),0,0);

     // MainWindow does other stuff
}
```

Comment: This question should be closed. The original post has already found the problem by himself (see the comments, the history of edition, and the last paragraph of the post).

Comment: @Tay2510: I do not follow. Finding the answer in comments (solved there) does not mean it is not a valid question that does not deserve an answer. If you feel it should be closed, just vote on it once you gain enough reputation. Note that, one close vote flag has already been dismissed, so the communiy has not agreed with you about it so far.